# Activeadmin custom sortable column in index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have custom sortable column 'Status' in index, how can I make it sortable?

```
 index do
    selectable_column

    column :title
    column :counter
    column 'Status', do |purchase|
      if purchase.status == 'verified' && purchase.expiration_date < DateTime.now.utc
        'ended'
      elsif purchase.status == 'verified' && purchase.expiration_date >= DateTime.now.utc
        'active'
      else
        purchase.status
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved a problem in this way

```
        column 'Status', sortable: :status do |purchase|
          if purchase.status == 'verified' && purchase.expiration_date < DateTime.now.utc
            'ended'
          elsif purchase.status == 'verified' && purchase.expiration_date >= DateTime.now.utc
            span class: "purchase-status-active" do
              'active'
            end
          else
            purchase.status
          end
        end


      controller do
        def find_collection(options = {})
          if params[:order] == 'status_desc'
            super.reorder(status: :desc, expiration_date: :desc)
          elsif params[:order] == 'status_asc'
            super.reorder(status: :asc, expiration_date: :asc)
          else
            super
          end
        end
      end
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages/index-as-table.html) you should be able to pass a `:sortable` key to the `column` call like so:

```
  index do
    # SNIP
    column 'Status', sortable: :status do |purchase|
      # SNIP
    end
  end
```

Comment: I know, but as you see it's custom column that depends on expiration_date field

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for index table custom sorting is on the [index as table page](https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages/index-as-table.html).